# Python requests throwing SSLError bad handshake with proxy connection

Tags: python, ssl, proxy

In Python Requests module, using proxy connection to browse some url

I added proxy ip and port to https_proxy and http_proxy environment variables to route the traffic to proxy

```
import os
import requests

os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "proxy1.xx.local:8081"
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "proxy1xx.local:8081"
H = {"X-Authenticated-User": "bharani@dummy.com"}
url = r"https://google.co.in"
r = requests.get(url,headers=H,verify=False)
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

Response I'm getting from above code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pilot.py", line 356, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url,headers=H,verify=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)
```

pyopenssl, ndg-httpsclient, pyasn1 are also installed.

Not sure What I'm missing.

Comment: Maybe you miss nothing. Have you checked with other applications like curl that it is even possible to access the specific URL using this proxy?

Comment: I didn't check curl, using fiddler i can able to achieve it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"using fiddler"* - fiddler is itself a proxy. Did you used your program with fiddler as proxy to directly access the site or did you configured  the `proxy1xx.local:8081` as upstream in fiddler or how exactly?

Comment: I added proxy ip proxy1xx.local:8081 to fiddler and ran my script. its workiing.

Comment: Is `proxy1xx.local:8081` some SSL intercepting proxy or just a plain proxy which will forward SSL without changes? Does your script with the same environment (notable same python) work when accessing the site directly, i.e. without proxy?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yeah its ssl intercepting proxy, Is there a way to send certificate along with request i,e requests.get(url,cert='cert.pem') like that